# currency default style on osclass

Tags: php, osclass

Hi guys i have a problem with the currency field!

When you are using one currency only you receive the default style! See image!

When you are using two or more currency's you receive a drop down box!

What i want to have is a box with the currency inside but a read only function!

This is on the item-post.php on osclass
and this is the code! how do i need to change this?

```
<?php ItemForm::currency_select(); ?>
```

[image: Default currency style]

Comment: It is better that you ask this question to osclass forum. There are very helpfull. https://forums.osclass.org/

Comment: I'am waiting already 3 weeks still no replay!

Comment: u have only one currency ?

Comment: yes only one currency i use

Comment: Look the answser, i have updated it by adding the input name, have added 'currency',

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have only one currency and this currency is the default one.

try this

```
<input name="currency" type="text" disabled="disabled" value="<?php echo osc_currency()?>">
```

And in your css try this

```
input[type="text"]:disabled {
background: #dddddd;
}
```

See the helpers of osclass which are here : https://doc.osclass.org/Helpers

Try it and tell me.